# Encrypting and storing new passwords via the Management Console

Tags: wso2, passwords, esb

I am trying to store password in wso2 management console so that I can refer it using an alias in my API configuration files. I am following below steps:
Manage -> Secure Vault Tool and then click Manage Passwords->
Add New Password to encrypt and store:
[management console: adding password alias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dXbZ.jpg)

After clicking on add I get the below error
"Failed to load security key store information ,Configure secret-conf.properties properly"

I am struggling with this issue, don't know what I am missing. I am new to ESB. 
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable encrypting passwords you have to configure ESB_HOME/repository/conf/security/secret-conf.properties file. You can do it automatically using the ciphertool.sh provided at ESB_HOME/bin. Run following and enter 'wso2carbon' as the password when asked. It will configure the file for you (and encrypt some plain text passwords in the config files),

```
./ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure
```

You have enter the same password 'wso2carbon' at the server startup again. For more details see [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon445/Securing+Passwords+in+Configuration+Files).

Comment: Thanks, but my question is why I am getting error from the management console? Its related to secret-config file. What do I need to configure in this file? I need to use password alias in my esb configuration file.

Comment: Yes, you get that error because the 'secret-conf.properties' file is not configured properly. ESB be will use keystore(custom, or default if you did not configure a custom one) to encrypt password and ESB has to know all the details like keystore location etc. Look at the 'secret-conf.properties' file after configuration and you will understand the requirement.

Comment: Thanks..I am able to add the alias password now.