# Using password aliases in WSO2 configuration file

Tags: passwords, wso2, expression, alias

I have a password alias and I need to use it in my API configuration file.

I am getting error in configuration after saving it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
`<property name="uri.var.Password" expression="wso2:vault-lookup('testenc.password')"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/xacml+json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:get-property('uri.var.Password')'))" scope="transport"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as  you tried the other question you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706463/encrypting-and-storing-new-passwords-via-the-management-console/). Add the password using Management Console, "Secure Vault Tool" section. Then refer the password in ESB synapse configuration file, using the alias you used.

Comment: I can refer the alias in my configuration file but I am facing issues while accessing it in authorization header property line. .

It is inside base 64 encode function.

Comment: Is that your original question? If so you have to edit the question to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi its done finally as  `<property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode(fn:concat('username:',get-property('Password'))))" scope="transport"/>` where "Password" is my alias password configured using secure vault.